# New in C++17: template templates that match by default

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

The C++17 standard says that one can do this:

```
template<class T, class U = T> class B { /* ... */ };
template<template<class> class P> class X { /* ... */ };

X<B> xb; // OK in C++17; ill formed in C++14
```

The C++14 standard makes the same code an error.

The old C++14 rule makes sense to me. The new C++17 rule does not. What changed?

For reference, the above sample code appears

- in sect. 17.3.3(3) of the C++17 standard (draft [here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)) and
- in sect. 14.3.3(2 or 3) of the C++14 standard (draft [here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)).

Comment: Some editors kindly add the [c++] tag to [c++14] and [c++17] questions. However, this question is probably too minor to interest general [c++] watchers. Only watchers who specifically watch [c++14] and/or [c++17] need notice.

Comment: Read the tag wikis, you *always* tag [tag:c++] along with the versioned ones.

Comment: @PasserBy Sure. That's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For brevity, the sample code omits details. Let us expand the sample:

```
template<class T, class U = T> class B { /* ... */ };
template<template<class> class P> class X {
    P<int, int> pii; // error: P has been declared to take only one argument
    P<int>      pi;  // OK
    P<char>     pc;  // OK
    /* ... */
};

X<B> xb; // OK in C++17; ill formed in C++14
```

The final line resolves `P<int>` as `B<int>`. It is true that the last means `B<int, int>`, but in view of the default parameter, `B<int>` is an unambiguous way to write that.

In principle, as far as I know, there was no reason C++14 could not have understood this, but the chain of reasoning was too complicated for C++14. Three years later, C++17 understands it.

Incidentally, the Clang C++ compiler offers a `-frelaxed-template-template-args` option to address the matter. If using template templates on Clang, you might assert this option. (@Rakete1111 is acknowledged for bringing the Clang option to attention.)

Comment: my confusion appears to be caused by language barrier, I incorrectly interpreted the second paragraph of the answer, which I understood just now. Deleted my original comment.

Comment: @Fureeish You are right. The second paragraph is terse, brief and condensed. The second paragraph could be written longer, but the topic is so confusing that I am not sure that longer would help. Fortunately, the *code* probably explains it better than the paragraph does.

Comment: Also might wanna mention -frelaxed-template-template-args is needed so that clang accepts this.

Comment: I would be glad to *accept* someone else's better answer rather than my own; but since my own remains the only, I shall accept it for now.